# To implement FlannBasedMatcher

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am doing a project on face recognition from video images.I extracted the features,now I need to compare the feature.So I found FlannBasedMatcher is a good method, also it is very fast.FlannBasedMatcher is already in the opencv (I am using opencv),but like to implement it myself with out any opencv help.Please help me to find what is exactly happening inside FlannBasedMatcher.Any response will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Features are typically compared using some distance metrics such as Euclidian distance between features that are considered to be points in some multi-demnsional space; one can use the angle between two vectors (that is feature vectors) that is independent of vector scaling; one can use a Humming distance for comparing binary strings, etc. The best way depends on the structure and the meaning of your feature vector. For faces it can be an angle between two vectors expressed through a dot product.

Now, flann is used for finding nearest neighbors and as such is not directly related to feature comparison though it can help to **speed up** finding similar features that are worth comparison (flann=fast library for nearest neighbors). Thus you won’t need to search through all your vectors trying to select the one that has highest dot product with the query vector, but instead directly compare a given face (vector) with just a few closest faces (vectors).

Finally, addressing a previous answer, in some cases one can use sparse arrays instead of KD trees. They are part of openCV too but can be implented through hash tables or trees. In sparse arrays you can check indices of neighboring elements which is analogous to flann nearest neighbors. Of course, sparse arrays are more limited than flann - for example, they require an exhaustive search in the neighborhood to get a nearest neighbors list but this is still faster than global search. Here is an example:

```
int dims = 3;
int sz[] = {1000, 1000, 1000}; // memory efficient
SparseMat M3d(dims, sz, CV_32F);
Point3i idx_sparse;
Vec3f p;

//set the element of a sparse 3D Mat
M3d.ref<Vec3f>(idx_sparse.x, idx_sparse.y, idx_sparse.z) = p; 

// iterate
SparseMatIterator it =  M3d.begin();
SparseMatIterator it_end = M3d.end();
for (; it != it_end; ++it) {

    // access existing element through iterator
    Vec3f vec = it.value<Vec3f>();

    // check neighbors if they exist
    int* idx = it.node()->index;
    idx[0]++; idx[1]--; idx[2]+=2;
    if (M3d.find(idx) != M3d.end()) {
        Vec3f vec = M3d.ref<Vec3f>(idx);
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain, how Sparse array can help in, for example, SIFT matching?

Comment: Here is a naive example. Imagine 1D feature (float) and thus 1D array which is just a histogram. You discretaize your features so that the features with similar values fall in the adjacent bins so you can search fast. Now moving to 128D SIFT space: implementing a multidimensional histogram is memory prohibitive but a sparse array can do without taking too much memory. There are pros and cons of course and in some cases you may want to use a KD-tree or K-means.

Comment: So, it is like take hash on SIFT descriptors and search across it neighbourhood? Thank you.

Comment: No, since the placement in hash table is not always ordered by index. So there is no concept of neighbor.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that easy. You have to implement kd-tree with aproximated nearest neighbor search. It is described in paper "[An Optimal Algorithm for Approximate Nearest
Neighbor Searching in Fixed Dimensions](http://www.cs.umd.edu/users/mount/Papers/dist.pdf)" by Arya et al.

If you don`t want to do it from the scratch and just want to get rid of OpenCV, you can take [original FLANN implementation](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/research/flann/).